# High score system using timer in c#

Tags: c#

I am making a high-score system but I am having trouble with comparing my new time with a time that is already saved in the text file.
I can save my time using StreamWriter but when I read the file using StreamRreader I can't compare it with my new time because the new time is an `int` and the timer I am reading out of the text file string. I tried to change the string to an `int` but I can't find a way that works. 
Thank you in advance!

Code I am using to read text:

```
string[] test = new string[5];

StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"test.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    test[i] = SR.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can you give code that write time in file?

Comment: Well, FIX YOUR CODE. Want help? Make a complete minimal example. Simple like that.

Comment: Yes, a [mcve] would be a great help. Give us code that we can run that shows how you are writing the file and the code for reading the file.

Comment: If you're writing an integer try `File.WriteAllText("file.txt", 42.ToString());` and to read an integer `int value = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText("file.txt"));`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the contents of the text file? You can only store string content in a text file, so you will have to read the contents of the file and then .Parse or .TryParse to convert the strings to the desired types (eg. Int)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you code will throw an IndexOutOfRangeException exception because you initialize a string array of 5 elements but you loop and try to add elements to the array 10 times.

It is unclear what you have in your text file. So, this is the simple way how to write, read and parse datetime in/from the text file:

```
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        // Write the string to a file.
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\folder\\test.txt");
        file.WriteLine(date);
        file.Close();

        // Read file
        DateTime dateTime;
        string firstRowFromFile = File.ReadLines("c:\\folder\\test.txt").First();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(firstRowFromFile, out dateTime))
        {
            // right datetime format
        }
        else
        {
            // wrong datetime format
        }
```

In real life this code should also use try/catch block to handle with exceptions properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the string before comparing:

Something similar like this:

```
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"test.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    test[i] = SR.ReadLine();

    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(test[i], "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: How do you know the content of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the result of ReadLine() to an int.

```
Convert.ToInt32(SR.ReadLine);
```

Assuming it is an int like you say.